# Color gradient fill in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, colors, gradient, pandas-styles

I have this panda dataframe:

[image]

and I need to add a color gradient fill in the WoE column, so that it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know if and how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.style` to plot a bar, aligned with 'zero', and you can specify the colors for positive and negative values. You will first need to make sure your Series has a numeric dtype, so that empty cell needs to be replaced with `NaN`

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ABCDEFG'),
                   'col2': list('xywerwr'),
                   'WOE': [-.08, -.03, .01, .09, .15, .24, '']})
```

#### Code

```
df['WOE'] = pd.to_numeric(df['WOE'])
df.style.bar(subset=['WOE'], align='zero', color=['#BA4B2F', '#7AAFe0'])
```

[image]